# Fix this Compile Error: identifier "and" is a special operator name in C++ [-Werror=c++-compat]?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, cmake

I added GTK library to my C++ project, and this error comes up.
How do I solve this?

Error happens in this line:

`line 84: GLIB_DEPRECATED_IN_2_54_FOR(g_object_new_with_properties and g_initable_init)`

of `/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/ginitable.h`.

Formally,

```
/usr/include/glib-2.0/gio/ginitable.h:84:58: error: identifier "and" is a special operator name in C++ [-Werror=c++-compat]
 GLIB_DEPRECATED_IN_2_54_FOR(g_object_new_with_properties and g_initable_init)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `-Werror`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either don't use `-Werror`, or use `-Wno-error=c++-compat` in addition to your current compilation flags.

In general, unconditional `-Werror` is [a bad](http://blog.schmorp.de/2016-02-27-tidbits-for-the-love-of-god-dont-use-werror.html) [idea](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/5/3/-werror-is-not-your-friend). It's better to selectively promote warnings to errors, like e.g. `-Werror=return-type`. Otherwise your project is bound to fail to compile with a different compiler or even a newer version of current compiler.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to adding the flag @Ruslan suggested, consider [filing a bug report against GTK](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/issues). While it's true that using `and` as an identifier is valid C, it's a pretty bad idea that can easily be avoided by changing the name to `and_` or to `conjunction` or something else.

Doing the former will fix the problem for *you*. Doing the latter may fix the problem for *everybody*...